# Extract actions on objects from a sentence in R

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp

I want to extract actions done on objects from a list of sentences in R. To give a small overview.

```
S = “The boy opened the box. He took the chocolates. He ate the chocolates. 
     He went to school”
```

I am looking for combinations as follows:

```
Opened box
Took chocolates
Ate chocolates
Went school
```

I have been able to get the verbs and the nouns extracted individually. But can’t figure out a way to combine them to get such insights.

```
library(openNLP)
library(openNLPmodels.en)
library(NLP)

s = as.String("The boy opened the box. He took the chocolates. He ate the 
               chocolates. He went to school")

tagPOS<-  function(x, ...) {
s <- as.String(x)
word_token_annotator<- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
a2 <- Annotation(1L, "sentence", 1L, nchar(s))
a2 <- annotate(s, word_token_annotator, a2)
a3 <- annotate(s, Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator(), a2)
a3w <- a3[a3$type == "word"]
POStags<- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
POStagged<- paste(sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], POStags), collapse = ",")
list(POStagged = POStagged, POStags = POStags)
}

nouns = c("/NN", "/NNS","/NNP","/NNPS")
verbs = c("/VB","/VBD","/VBG","/VBN","/VBP","/VBZ")

s = tolower(s)
s = gsub("\n","",s)
s = gsub('"',"",s)

tags = tagPOS(s)
tags = tags$POStagged
tags = unlist(strsplit(tags, split=","))

nouns_present = tags[grepl(paste(nouns, collapse = "|"), tags)]
nouns_present = unique(nouns_present)
verbs_present = tags[grepl(paste(verbs, collapse = "|"), tags)]
verbs_present = unique(verbs_present)
nouns_present<- gsub("^(.*?)/.*", "\\1", nouns_present)
verbs_present = gsub("^(.*?)/.*", "\\1", verbs_present)
nouns_present = 
paste("'",as.character(nouns_present),"'",collapse=",",sep="")
verbs_present = 
paste("'",as.character(verbs_present),"'",collapse=",",sep="")
```

The idea is to build a network graph where on clicking on an verb node, all the objects attached to it will come up and vice versa.
Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you also want to get the words before and after your key action verbs. I was able to achieve this by using `tidytext` package. (Reference link: https://uc-r.github.io/word_relationships)

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)

#first create another column with divided up text strings by n(i set as every two words paired together)
mydf <-unnest_tokens(comments, "tokens", Response, token = "ngrams", n=2, to_lower = TRUE, drop = FALSE)

#remove stopwords:
mydf %>%
  separate(tokens, c("word1", "word2"), sep = " ") %>%
  filter(!word1 %in% stop_words$word,
         !word2 %in% stop_words$word,
         ) %>%
  count(word1, word2, sort = TRUE) %>% view()
```